# scalatest assert that either is right results in symbol literal is deprecated warning

Tags: scala

I am using ScalaTest version 3.2.2 on Scala version 2.13.4

I am writing a test for an API with returns an either and I want to test if the results are right. based on the [documentation](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_EitherValues) I wrote this code

```
val symbolEither: Either[io.circe.Error, Symbol] = decode[Symbol](input)
symbolEither should be('right)
val symbol = symbolEither.right.value
```

but I'm getting warnings at compilation time

```
[warn] JsonSerializationTest.scala:20:28: symbol literal is deprecated; use Symbol("right") instead
[warn]     symbolEither should be('right)
[warn]                            ^
[warn] JsonSerializationTest.scala:21:37: method get in class RightProjection is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Use `Either.getOrElse` instead
[warn]     val symbol = symbolEither.right.get
[warn] JsonSerializationTest.scala:21:31: method right in class Either is deprecated (since 2.13.0): Either is now right-biased, use methods directly on Either
[warn]     val symbol = symbolEither.right.get
```

does anyone know how to get rid of these warnings. the messages are not helpful. what does `Symbol("right")` even mean?